# HTML Navbar scaling page instead of moving content

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a problem. On my site http://www.veniria.esy.es when I'm swiping out the navbar, the content should move to the right with the navbar - and it do so - on PC. When I'm trying to swipe out the navbar on smartphone, the whole page scales down, and I don't know why. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set up your viewport for mobile. Just add this to your `<head>`

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Worked for a while, but since when I have changed menu a bit, it keeps zooming in .-.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't deleted the `<meta>` tag again? Since it not there now.

Comment: Ah, It was a mistake - I meant that now it works properly, but when I enter the page it zooms in

Comment: Well the question was why it zooms out. It was answered. Making it responsive wasn't mentioned. You should use % rather than absolute values for your sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on iPhone and it didn't scale down to me.
However, I noticed the viewport is not mobile friendly.

Try putting this on inside `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```